# How to authentice users with SOAP?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, nusoap

Do we have to send username/password along with the SOAP message ?
In that case, my database server will have to run a query every time to authenticate.

Is there a method for token based authentication ? It would be really helpful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In our environment, yes.  But we're using Cisco and/or Layer7 gateways which perform the authentication, so by the time it gets to the application server, it's on the internal network and trusted.

Alternately, you could pass a userid/password and some sort of Token string.  Your server would look at the token and see if it passes a "sniff" test (too old? Zero length? Checksum bad? coming from wrong IP?) if it sniffs ok, it's ok.  If it's not ok (typically blank), then use the userid/password to authenticate, generate a new token with a current timestamp, and use their IP addr (or something) to generate the new token.  Maybe throw a GUID in there for uniqueness. If they don't have anything valid (token bad, userid/password missing), then send a challenge back, so they can re-submit with userid/password onboard.